# How can i make space after punctations in C

Tags: c++, c

My Homework is
Some certain punctuations, period (.), comma (,), colon (:), semi-colon (;), question mark
(?), and exclamation mark(!), should be followed by a space. For example, the following
strings should be corrected because there is no space after the above punctuations.
(There might be some other punctuations which need a space after; however, given
punctuations (.,:;?!) will suffice)
I saw you playing soccer.You are such a good player.
I saw you playing soccer. You are such a good player.
Hello!How are you?Fine thanks,and you.
Hello! How are you? Fine thanks, and you.

I am trying to make space after all punctations but i getting error

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(){
char string[200];
scanf("%s", string[200]);
char string1[200] = " ";
for(int i=0;i<strlen(string);i++){
if( s[i] !='.' && ',' && ';' && ':' && '!' && '?'){

  string1 = string1 + string[i];

}



else{

  string1= string1 + string[i] + " ";

}
}
string = string1;
printf("new string : %s", string);
return 0;
}
```

can someone help me  or can someone convert my c++ code to C

```
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string s;
cout<<"Please enter the string"<<endl;
cin>>s;

cout<<"Input string:"<<s<<endl;
string s1="";
for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
{
    if(s[i]!='.'&&s[i]!=','&&s[i]!=';'&&s[i]!=':'&&s[i]!='!'&&s[i]!='?')
    s1=s1+s[i];
    else
    s1=s1+s[i]+" ";
}
s=s1;
cout<<"Updated string:"<<s<<endl;
return 0;
}
```

I am trying to make space but cant in C lang can someone figured out ?

Comment: You need `strcat` to join strings in c

Comment: `if` clause that checks for punctuation characters in C code is incorrect. In C++ code is correct.

Comment: Why the C++ tag if you are programming in C?  C and C++ are distinct languages.  For example, C++ has `std::string` type and C doesn't.  Please adjust tags appropriately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operator `+` does not work on operands of type `char[]`. You should just copy the characters to `string1`:

```
for(int i = 0, i1 = 0, string_length = strlen(string); i < string_length; i++)
{
    string1[i1++] = string[i];

    if (string[i] is one of the punctuation characters)
        string1[i1++] = ' ';
}
```

I moved `strlen` call to initialization part of the `for` loop so that it's called only once, instead of many times.

But pay attention to one minor problem with this code. If the punctuation character is already followed by a space then the resulting string will have two spaces. If you are not fine with this then you would have to add more code.

Comment: Thanks for answer

Answer (score 0):

I was rewriting something similar, this problem is basically parsing 101 "Hello World".

I rewrote your for loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++)
{
     if (ispunct(s[i]))
     {
          if (s[i] == '.' || '!' || '?' || ',')
          {
              t = t + s[i] + ' ';
          }
          else
          {
               t = t + s[i];
          }
     }
     else
     {
     t = t + s[i];
     }
}
```

s is string one and t is string two.

The biggest change was in using the function ispunct which checks if the character fed into it is a punctuation mark.

Second biggest change was swapping from logical AND to logical OR in the comparison.

Third biggest change I made the comparison a equivalent test "==", rather than a "!=" Not Equal test.

It's a very useful little block of code when tokenizing, parsing, or formatting text inputs in a program.

Comment: `if (s[i] == '.' || '!' || '?' || ',')` doesn't do what you think it does. It will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Also, the `ispunct` check is not needed because your `else` clause in both branches does the same thing.